# Publish App to azure functions failing with Repository changed its 'Suite' value from 'stable-updates' to 'oldstable-updates'

Tags: python, azure, docker, azure-functions-docker

I am publishing my python application with this command:
`func azure functionapp publish myapp --build-native-deps --additional-packages cmake opencv-python-headless`

it pulls the microsoft docker image, and then spins up a container and throws this error :

`N: Repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'stable' to 'oldstable'`

`N: Repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security stable-security InRelease' changed its 'Version' value from '11' to '12'`

`E: Repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security stable-security InRelease' changed its 'Codename' value from 'bullseye-security' to 'bookworm-security'`

`N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.`

`N: Repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'stable-security' to 'oldstable-security'`

`N: Repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'stable-updates' to 'oldstable-updates'`

I have tried to clearing out space to make more memory available
i also tried using the bash container to access that image, it gets fixed but when i try to publish my app
it spins up a totally different container and i get the same error

I don't have much experience doing this, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian' has changed its 'Suite' value from 'stable' to 'oldstable'. This can happen when the Debian distribution undergoes a new release, and the repositories are updated accordingly.

- Instead of relying on the default Microsoft Docker image, I have created a Dockerfile in my python application root folder.

**Dockerfile :**

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

# Install additional dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends cmake

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the application code to the container
COPY . /app

# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Set the entry point for the function app
CMD ["main"]
```

- To build the Docker image I used the below command:

```
docker build -t myapp .
```

- I am able to create Docker Image.
  [image]
- Publish the app to Azure function by the below command line.

```
func azure functionapp publish myapp --docker-container myapp
```

- Here I can see the Docker image converting into Container.

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot, i really appreciate this

Does this mean i have to create a function app for containers rather than code

Just for clarification

Comment: Yes @wisdom, it will be easy rather than writing a code. please check and follow from the above.